# Converting xml to json using axios

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios

```
  componentDidMount() {
    axios.get('http://thecatapi.com/api/images/get?format=xml&results_per_page=20')
    .then((response) => {
      console.log(response.data);
    });
  }
```

my response.data is just an xml file, how can I parse this to json I have tried > `(JSON.parse()`. I then want to set the state and put each cat as an object in my array.

but when I do `this.setState(cats: this.state.cats.concat(response)` I just an array with one big object in it

I'm confused as to do what to do when I get my response back and how to use it

thanks

response.data im getting at the moment:

```
<response>
  <data>
    <images>
      <image>
        <url>http://24.media.tumblr.com/tumblr_m4ceddr9GM1qcxyrro1_1280.jpg</url>
        <id>de5</id>
        <source_url>http://thecatapi.com/?id=de5</source_url>
      </image>
      <image>
        <url>http://24.media.tumblr.com/tumblr_lwgyvtZTRT1qhpojco1_500.jpg</url>
        <id>50f</id>
        <source_url>http://thecatapi.com/?id=50f</source_url>
      </image>
      <image>
        <url>http://25.media.tumblr.com/tumblr_lzobekds0b1qgjltdo1_1280.jpg</url>
        <id>c8v</id>
        <source_url>http://thecatapi.com/?id=c8v</source_url>
      </image>
      <image>
        <url>http://25.media.tumblr.com/YuqJHp0AQh2ggs7tGJThUhhyo1_1280.jpg</url>
        <id>ah7</id>
        <source_url>http://thecatapi.com/?id=ah7</source_url>
      </image>
      <image>
        <url>http://25.media.tumblr.com/tumblr_m1mg9xfGfN1qay66po1_500.jpg</url>
        <id>354</id>
        <source_url>http://thecatapi.com/?id=354</source_url>
      </image>
      <image>
        <url>http://24.media.tumblr.com/tumblr_ma7jlxaQrH1r6jd7fo1_500.jpg</url>
        <id>MjA2NDUzMg</id>
        <source_url>http://thecatapi.com/?id=MjA2NDUzMg</source_url>
      </image>
      <image>
        <url>http://24.media.tumblr.com/tumblr_lnjo1hH8DW1qljvf7o1_400.jpg</url>
        <id>cl2</id>
        <source_url>http://thecatapi.com/?id=cl2</source_url>
      </image>
      <image>
        <url>http://25.media.tumblr.com/tumblr_m2pi5dzrUr1rohhvpo1_1280.jpg</url>
        <id>47u</id>
        <source_url>http://thecatapi.com/?id=47u</source_url>
      </image>
      <image>
        <url>http://25.media.tumblr.com/tumblr_mcey3xJG7K1qzex9io1_500.jpg</url>
        <id>MTUyNDU4Ng</id>
        <source_url>http://thecatapi.com/?id=MTUyNDU4Ng</source_url>
      </image>
      <image>
        <url>http://24.media.tumblr.com/tumblr_lmtz3wcDVg1qz5b0yo1_1280.jpg</url>
        <id>MTg3MzgwMA</id>
        <source_url>http://thecatapi.com/?id=MTg3MzgwMA</source_url>
      </image>
      <image>
        <url>http://25.media.tumblr.com/tumblr_m3v14bcN4o1qz4ueho1_1280.jpg</url>
        <id>3u1</id>
        <source_url>http://thecatapi.com/?id=3u1</source_url>
      </image>
      <image>
        <url>http://25.media.tumblr.com/tumblr_lwlgt2LesO1qe49wpo1_500.jpg</url>
        <id>6pk</id>
        <source_url>http://thecatapi.com/?id=6pk</source_url>
      </image>
      <image>
        <url>http://25.media.tumblr.com/tumblr_m4ilnjcGek1r6jd7fo1_500.jpg</url>
        <id>egj</id>
        <source_url>http://thecatapi.com/?id=egj</source_url>
      </image>
      <image>
        <url>http://25.media.tumblr.com/tumblr_ltsphdITe71qehxqmo1_400.gif</url>
        <id>5td</id>
        <source_url>http://thecatapi.com/?id=5td</source_url>
      </image>
      <image>
        <url>http://24.media.tumblr.com/tumblr_m1jodvuOuz1qzyqubo1_1280.jpg</url>
        <id>a03</id>
        <source_url>http://thecatapi.com/?id=a03</source_url>
      </image>
      <image>
        <url>http://29.media.tumblr.com/Jjkybd3nSjcof95aUBOP7Rl2o1_500.jpg</url>
        <id>2cd</id>
        <source_url>http://thecatapi.com/?id=2cd</source_url>
      </image>
      <image>
        <url>http://25.media.tumblr.com/tumblr_lz81x4TNCE1rpsftmo1_500.gif</url>
        <id>4ha</id>
        <source_url>http://thecatapi.com/?id=4ha</source_url>
      </image>
      <image>
        <url>http://24.media.tumblr.com/tumblr_lncvcuNpEB1qbe5pxo1_500.jpg</url>
        <id>9hs</id>
        <source_url>http://thecatapi.com/?id=9hs</source_url>
      </image>
      <image>
        <url>http://24.media.tumblr.com/tumblr_m52cqek4wK1rurnfyo1_400.gif</url>
        <id>MTU2NzAyOA</id>
        <source_url>http://thecatapi.com/?id=MTU2NzAyOA</source_url>
      </image>
      <image>
        <url>http://25.media.tumblr.com/tumblr_m2tglif3SI1r73wdao1_500.jpg</url>
        <id>7qk</id>
        <source_url>http://thecatapi.com/?id=7qk</source_url>
      </image>
    </images>
  </data>
</response>
```

Comment: can you show what the response.date looks like

Comment: @Omar done mate

Comment: I'm curious to know if you change the `format=xml` in the URL to `format=json`, would that perhaps return the JSON you want?

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan I did try that but http://thecatapi.com/docs.html#get says it can only be html, src or xml

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/xml-js

Comment: I don't believe there's an inbuilt simple way to do this. There's NPM modules that convert XML to JSON or JavaScript objects (and vice versa).  Then you can post-process the JSON/object as you wish. Check out xml2js to start with.